# how to render multiple things separately

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine, render-layers, render-passes

I'm using Blender 2.80. I have a scene, where I fire 20 cannons at the same time, with smoke and fire. How can I render (with Eevee render) some cannons separatley?

(i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png)[image]

Comment: You need to move each of the cannons and their smoke domain to a different collection. Then create different view layers and enable the object you want in each layer and disable the rest. Then use the compositor to bring it all together.

Comment: Is there a way, where I can render one complete scene of my cannon firing. And then later on blend it in multiple times, with my video?

Comment: If you want to do it in a single render, I'd use Cryptomatte which is super powerful for this kind of work. Objects will still be occluded by objects in front of them in the camera view though. If you need to entire object visible even if something is in front of it, do as cegaton said and add them to different collections then render those collections separately and then composite later.
https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/compositing/types/matte/cryptomatte.html

Comment: thanks allot for this

Answer (score 0):

This tutorial explains how to work with view/render layers
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jOO3K1B9vgg

View layers is to render separately.
render layers is how you combine them in compositing.

Comment: I tried following this, but I don't get cast shadows from collections that are disabled onto rendered collections that are enabled. Can you not render with proper occlusion?

Comment: This is a question about Blender 3.4